# How can I select a “music store” subcategory for my new Facebook Page? I can't find it but I can see other businesses are listed as it

Tags: facebook-pages

I'm trying to set up a Facebook page for a new physical record shop. My competitors that are already in business seem to have selected the subcategory “music store,” but I can't see it anywhere. How do I select this category for my page?